# Camera don't works properly without UI

Tags: android, user-interface, camera

I'm making for educational purposes, a Android APP.
This APP, call to service (the service die when the task is finished) and take a photo without UI, and without sound.

This APP works good in my old HTC Desire (rooted) but dont start in Nexus4. What I'm doing wrong? Why works in certanly phones but not in others?

Code:

```
public class OIM_CameraControl extends Service
{       

private final IBinder mBinder = new OIM_CameraControlBinder();  
private Camera mCamera;
private Parameters parameters;
private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    try {

        SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());


        if(mCamera == null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {


                Camera.CameraInfo info=new Camera.CameraInfo();

                    for (int i=0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {                   
                    Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);

                    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {

                        mCamera=Camera.open(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (mCamera == null) {
            System.out.println("No se ha detectado ninguna camara");
            mCamera=Camera.open();
        }


        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());

        // I tried change parameters, add new parameters, delete parameters
        // a lot of combinations,... never works in Nexus4.
        parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(720, 480);
        parameters.setPictureSize(720, 480);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED);
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        parameters.setZoom(0);
        parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
        parameters.set("rotation",90);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY;

}

private Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() 
{
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
    {
//Do something
    }
};

//CLASES INTERNAS DE BINDER
public class OIM_CameraControlBinder extends Binder {
    public OIM_CameraControl getService() {
        return  OIM_CameraControl.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
```

In my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

LogCat:

```
06-17 11:25:29.620: D/Camera(14346): app passed NULL surface
06-17 11:25:29.650: W/System.err(14346): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1095)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1040)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at com.obviousdevelop.estigia.objects.implement.OIM_CameraControl.onStartCommand(OIM_CameraControl.java:57)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2656)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-17 11:25:29.660: W/System.err(14346):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put whole logcat here.

Comment: I edit the post and added the LOGCAT. Also agree new parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Check, have you call `Camera.startPreview()` again after taken a picture.

Also follow link and check your code and match with that..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: I tried this, but nothing changes. The logs explains the same, TakePicture Failed. 

I have read the API of the camera and it seems that everything is correct, also, on my HTC Desire it works ...

Anyway, Thanks Segi!